# ZipArchive is not creating - addFile() returns false

Tags: php, pdo, permissions, zip, hosting

I want to zip a file using PHP. The following code works fine with XAMPP on my local machine, but not on hosting site.

First I thouught it was file permission problem, but I changed it to 777 and nothing changed.

Secondly, I read somewhere on Internet that zip extension may not be loaded but funtcion extension_loaded('zip') return true and there is no errors.

Thirdly, I have checked the result of zipArchive funtions - in my case, $zip->open() returns true, $zip->addFile() return false and $zip->close() return true. But zip file isn't created. It seems like permissions issue, but I have set 777 for both .php and .txt file which I want to add to a zip file.

PHP version on my local machine: 7.3.4
PHP version on my hosting provider: 7.3.1

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();

$DelFilePath="raport_X_.zip";
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/www/Rekrutacja/raports/".$DelFilePath)) {
        unlink ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/www/Rekrutacja/raports/".$DelFilePath); 
}       

$openResult = $zip->open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/www/Rekrutacja/raports/".$DelFilePath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);


$file='BranżowaSzkołaIstopniamechanikpojazdówsamochodowychGIMNAZJUM_RAPORT.txt';

$addResult = $zip->addFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/www/Rekrutacja/raports/".$file,$file);
$closeResult = $zip->close(); 

$path = 'raports/raport_X_.zip';  
$filename = "raport_X_.zip";  
if(file_exists($path)){
    header("Content-Type:application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
    header("Cache-control: private");
    header('X-Sendfile: '.$path);
    readfile($path);
    exit;
}
echo '<br>';
if(extension_loaded('zip')){
    echo 'Zip extension is loaded <br>';
    }
echo 'Open result:';
var_dump($openResult);
echo 'Add error:';
var_dump($addResult);
 echo 'Close error:';
 var_dump($closeResult);
 phpinfo();
 ?>
```

I simply want to get a zip with a .txt file in it. I am getting no error, but zip file isn't created. It works on XAMPP, but not on hosting. I wasted a lot of time on it and now I got no idea.

Comment: Maybe try https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstatusstring.php to find out what the error may be?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added this method in 3 places - after object initialization, after add method and after close method. And I got now 2 warnings "Warning: PHP Startup: Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in ...". There is no warning after addFile() method, and after that it returns " No error". In other cases, getStatusString() returns nothing.